# How to get app name from electron renderer?

Tags: electron

I'm using an Electron React boilerplate and I'm interested in getting the app name from inside one of my react component file.

I've tried this

```
import {app} from 'electron'
const name = app.getName()
```

but I get the error

> hot update failed for module "./app/containers/Root.tsx". Last file processed: "./app/components/Modal/Text.tsx".

I'm guessing electron cannot be accessed from the "renderer"? what's the best way to access this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: Send a message to the main process and have it send back a message containing the app name.

You're correct that you can't get the app name from the renderer.

So I'd send a message to the main process requesting the app name, then have the main process send back the app name.

This is how the code would look:

**renderer.js**

```
var ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Send message.
ipcRenderer.send('asynchronous-message', 'getAppName');

// Recieve app name.
ipcRenderer.on('asynchronous-message', function (evt, messageObj) {
    console.log(messageObj); // This will contain the app name.
});
```

**main.js**

```
var ipcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;
var app     = require('electron').app;

ipcMain.on('asynchronous-message', function (evt, messageObj) {
    // Send message back to renderer.
    if (messageObj == 'getAppName') {
        evt.sender.webContents.send('asynchronous-message', app.getName());
    }
});
```

[Docs for `ipcMain`.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main)

[Docs for `ipcRenderer`.](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer)